# C# - Cannot send email, called through multiple dlls

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, dll, smtpclient

I have 3 dlls:

- my asp.net application [aspnet]
- steam api manager [Steam.dll]
- notification manager [Notifications.dll]

I need to count steam api requests (they are limited to 100K per day) and in the end of the day, I want to send email about total requests per day I made.

```
    //My aspnet app global.asax
    protected void Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Steam.RequestCounter.Run();        
    }

    //Steam.dll
    public static void Run()
    {
       // .. request count logic

        Notifications.SendEmail();
    }

    //Notifications.dll
    public static void SendEmail()
    {
       //..email sending logic
    }
```

If the call stack looks like above, the email is not send. Why?
If I call `Notifications.SendEmail()` method directly from my asp .net app (global.asax) it works.
Can you please explain me what is going on?

**EDIT**:

There is no error during the call. SmtpClient.Send() method pass normally. Even if I put it into try, catch block, no exception occured.

This is my Notifications.SendEmail method:

```
    public static void SendEmail(string subject, string body, params string[] recipients)
    {
        const string sender = "xxxx@outlook.com";
        var client = new SmtpClient("smtp-mail.outlook.com")
        {
            Port = 587,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false
        };

        var credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(sender, "xxxx");
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Credentials = credentials;

        var mail = new MailMessage {From = new MailAddress(sender)};
        foreach (var recipient in recipients)
        {
            mail.To.Add(recipient);
        }
        mail.Subject = subject;
        mail.Body = body;
        client.Send(mail);
    }
```

This is scenario when email is sent (inside global.asax):

```
    protected void Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //call directly to Notifications.dll
        Email.SendEmail(
            "subject",
            "body",
            "xxx@outlook.com"
        );        
    }
```

This is scenario when email is not sent:

```
    protected void Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //call to Steam.dll
        Steam.RequestCounter.Run();        
    }

    //Inside Steam.dll
    public static void Run()
    {
        SendEmail();
    }

    private static void SendEmail()
    {
        //call to Notifications.dll
        Email.SendEmail(
            "subject",
            "body",
            "xxx@outlook.com"
        ); 
    }
```

So problem is not in request counting logic. I think problem is with references. Maybe host environment(asp.net app) don't have everything what it needs to send the email. I don't know how to check it, if no error occurred.

Comment: Can you post your entire code ? Maybe the Run() method raise some error and SendEMail is not called. Try to refactor the Run() to return the count and after call the sendemail passing it a parameters, all called on asp.net to try if succeed

Comment: In sample you've posted there is no difference between "directly from my asp .net app (global.asax) it works" - `SendEMail` is unconditionally called from `Application_Strart` that normally is in "global.asax". You need to provide better (but still small) sample as well as what "email is not send" means (i.e. `SendEMail` called but fails vs. `SendEMail` not called at all).

Comment: Where does the `SendEmail` method get its settings (credentials and other)? Are these dlls all running inside ASP.NET, i.e. referenced and used by the web app?

Comment: You can see that I set credentials of sender inside Notifications.dll . It doesn't matter, it is just for testing purposes. And yes I have references to Notifications.dll and Steam.dll inside my asp.net app. But stuff from Notifications.dll is not used in my web app. I only use method from Steam.dll and Steam.dll calls Method from Notifications.dll. Maybe here is a problem?

Answer (score 1):

The function in your global.asax will called once - when you Start your application. So if no recycle or deploy occurred it will run on i.e. Monday and never again. You need some time trigger, scheduler, service or something like this

Comment: I didn't want to bother you with my scheduler if the problem still exist, even if I remove my scheduled logic. See my edit.